# @RequestPart is always null with Multipart Request, Spring MVC 3.2.4

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am developing a small RESTful service based on Spring 3.2.4 and following [this article](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-update/blob/master/multipart-requests/slides.md) to write a custom function to send Multipart Requests.

Firstly, in the controller, I wrote the sample function to test

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createUser(@RequestBody User user)
{
    if (user != null) {
        log.debug("Username: " + user.getUsername());
    }

    return "Successfully created!";
}
```

The User object contains a user information which is using **Jackson JSON** to get and parse data. I also used the cURL to send request and the command I tested

```
curl http://localhost:8080/user/createUser --data-binary @test.txt -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This is the **text.txt**

```
{    
    "id" : "123456",
    "username" : "YOUR_USERNAME",
    "password" : "YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "email" : "YOUR_EMAIL"
}
```

The application returned "Successfully created!" and logged the username. It worked fine.

Secondly, I thought everything would be simple but I was wrong. When I wrote the following function to send Multipart Requests with the User and MultipartFile objects.

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/createUser", 
        method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = {"multipart/mixed", "multipart/form-data"})
public @ResponseBody String createUser(
           @RequestPart("user") @Valid User user, 
           @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

    if (user != null) {
        log.debug("Username: " + user.getUsername());    // The username is null
    }

    return "Successfully created!";
}
```

I continued to use the cURL to test with the command

```
curl http://localhost:8080/user/createUser --data-binary @test.txt -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=4ebf00fbcf09"
```

And the **text.txt** file was changed

```
--4ebf00fbcf09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{    
    "id" : "123456",
    "username" : "YOUR_USERNAME",
    "password" : "YOUR_PASSWORD",
    "email" : "YOUR_EMAIL"
}

--4ebf00fbcf09
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="no_thumb.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<... File Data ...>

--4ebf00fbcf09--
```

I am facing the problem that the @RequestPart is always **NULL**. Details:

- The application returned "Successfully created!"
- The User object was not null but the server logged the **"Username: null"** and MultipartFile object was too.

How can I fix it?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you seen this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers?

Comment: Yes, I have. I changed my code that followed this doc but I still got the "Username: null". Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Answer is bit late, but could be useful still. This is what worked for me to attach both a payload and a file, with @RequestPart

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestPart Blah blah, 
        @RequestPart(value = "uploadfile", required=false) MultipartFile) {...}
```

And with curl command below I'm able to verify this as well

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed" \
-F "blah={\"name\":\"mypayloadname\"};type=application/json" \
-F "uploadfile=@somevalid.zip" http://localhost:8080/url/path
```

Make sure you escape the payload content and somevalid.zip (second -F is optional, since required is set to false) should be there in the same directory where curl is executed or replace it with valid path to the file.